# usar range con decimales en ciclo for, Python

Tags: python, bucle-for, float

Buen dia tengo un problema. Estoy intentando utilizar un numero decimal dentro de un range para un for, Practicamente necesito que el for haga el ciclo hasta llegar al numero decimal pero redondeandolo y me imprima el numero sin redondear.

dejo codigo.

Aqui me imprimirá del 1 hasta el 13 por el `round(float('12.5'))` pero quiero que el ciclo se haga 13 veces y me imprimira del 1 hasta el 12.5. Cabe recalcar que el `12.5` es una cadena.

```
x = range(1,round(float('12.5')+1))
for n in x:
  print(n)
```

Osea busco un resultado asi.

```
1
2
..
11
12
12.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este código imprime hasta el último valor entero y luego el valor con decimales

```
valor = "12.5"
for x in [*range(1, int(float(valor)) + 1), valor]:
    print(x)
```

produce:

```
1
2
...
12
12.5
```

Y con `valor = "12.0005"` produce

```
1
2
...
11
12
12.0005
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente sería añadir al ciclo `range(1, n)` un último elemento, algo así:

```py
from math import ceil

n = float('12.5')

for i in (*range(1, ceil(n)), n):
    print(i)
```

Resultado:

```
1
2
...
12
12.5
```

La tupla para controlar el bucle for se crea en el momento. Si fuera muy grande (eg: `n==12e100`) gastaría mucha memoria y daría error. Para evitar problemas lo mejor es usar una cadena de iteradores:

```py
from itertools import chain
from math import ceil

n = float('12.5e100')

for i in chain(range(1, ceil(n)), [n]):
    print(i)
    if i > 100:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes incluir una sentencia `if` y un `break` así:

```
i = 12.5
x = range(1,round(i + 1))
for n in x:
    if n == round(i):
        print(i)
        break
    else:
        print(n)
```